# Raspberry PI 3 not able to save video

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

The following code works perfectly on my raspberry pi 3 (raspbian unix OS). and I can see the preview of the video for 10 seconds. (so looks like camera is installed correctly).

```
from camera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
sleep(10)
camera.stop_preview()
camera.close()
```

but if I try to save the preview to a file by

```
from camera import PiCamera
from time import sleep
camera = PiCamera()
camera.start_preview()
camera.start_recording("./foo.h264")
sleep(10)
camera.stop_recording()
camera.stop_preview()
```

then I get an error

```
mmal: mmal_vc_component_enable: failed to enable component: ENOSPC
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CaptureVideo.py", line 3, in <module>
    camera = PiCamera()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 488, in __init__
    self.STEREO_MODES[stereo_mode], stereo_decimate)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/camera.py", line 620, in _init_camera
    prefix="Camera component couldn't be enabled")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/picamera/exc.py", line 191, in mmal_check
    raise PiCameraMMALError(status, prefix)
picamera.exc.PiCameraMMALError: Camera component couldn't be enabled: Out of resources (other than memory)
```

I did google the error message but didn't find a concrete answer.

Edit:: My `gpu_mem` is 128 in /boot/config.txt

Edit2:: I found this project on github

https://github.com/ashtons/picam

I installed this project and wrote the following code

```
import picam
import time
picam.recordVideoWithDetails('./foo.h264', 640, 480, 10000)
```

and it worked and it recorded the video. the video looked as if its fast forward. but it worked and didn't run out of resources.

So now the question is what is wrong with PiCamera module

Comment: What if you turn the camera on and off, reboot the Pi, add `camera.close()` to the script that saves the preview and try running it again?

Comment: same. error. I added `camera.close()` at the end of the script. now I shutdown rp3 and pulled out power cord. then reattached power and booted rp3. ran the script. same result

Comment: Shucks. I don't have a camera myself but I've seen variations of this error pop up on SO and the Raspberry Pi site a few times. The answers/suggestions seem to vary wildly from "make sure nothing else is using the camera" to "your camera port is broken! Get a new Pi!". [This](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/26829/picamera-not-working) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27468543/picamera-cannot-be-initialized-as-a-class-member-when-the-script-is-run-from-com) might be relevant. I wonder if it matters that the traceback mentions line 3 (errors out before recording?)